# Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать смену иконки на кнопке при клике на нее

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка

```
<button onclick="hidetxt('nn');" class="buttonfirst">
  <p style="margin: 0px px 5px 5px; font-size:17px;">
    Все условия акции
  </p>
  <i style="margin-top: -10px !important;" class="icon-down-open-big"></i>
</button>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на нее иконка сменялась на icon-up-open-big

Comment: `document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => { this.querySelector('i').className = 'icon-up-open-big'; });`

Comment: @InDevX: а почему не `document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => { this.querySelector('i').className = 'icon-down-close-big'; });` ? ;-)

Comment: @UModeL так `icon-down-close-big` по умолчанию, а менять надо на `icon-up-open-big`

Comment: Странно, почему-то не работает(

Comment: @InDevX: хех. Не доглядел )))

Comment: @Григорий а так `document.querySelector('.buttonfirst').addEventListener('click', () => { this.querySelector('i').className = 'icon-up-open-big'; });`?

Comment: @InDevX 
И так ничего не происходит... Может быть я его куда-то не туда вставляю, или еще что-то упускаю?

Comment: @InDevX а this в стрелочной функции разве передается?

Comment: Так должно работать - document.querySelector('.buttonfirst').addEventListener('click', function() { this.querySelector('i').className = 'icon-up-open-big'; });

Comment: @PavelNazarian ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо!!!!!))) Все работает, а еще один вопрос, а как еще текст сменить при этом на "Скрыть условия акции"?)

Comment: @PavelNazarian и как сделать так, чтобы при еще одном клике она обратно менялась?)

Comment: @Григорий https://jsfiddle.net/u8vjx6r2/

Comment: @PavelNazarian Спасибо огромное! Очень выручили

Comment: @Григорий не за что. Но на будущее - на этом ресурсе принято не просто вопросы задавать, но и прилагать к нему свои попытки решения вопроса.

Comment: @PavelNazarian Просто все мои попытки свелись к полному провалу, я еще очень новичок( Скрипт, кстати, почему-то не работает на мобильной версии, хотя там назвал класс кнопки по другому и вот тоже ломаю голову с чем это может быть вообще связано?

Comment: @PavelNazarian разобрался)) Еще раз спасибо за помощь

Comment: @PavelNazarian Спасибо что исправили, по привычке написал

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hidetxt = ($btn) => {
  const $i = $btn.querySelector(`i`);

  $i.classList.toggle(`icon-down-open-big`);
  $i.classList.toggle(`icon-up-open-big`);
}
```

```css
i.icon-down-open-big:after {
  content: ' down'
}

i.icon-up-open-big:after {
  content: ' up'
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hidetxt(this,'nn');" class="buttonfirst">
  <p style="margin: 0px px 5px 5px; font-size:17px;">
    Все условия акции
  </p>
  <i style="margin-top: -10px !important;" class="icon-down-open-big"></i>
</button>
```